# A question on the convex hull of independent random walks

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, random-walks

Consider $m$ independent random walks $X^1_n, \dots, X^m_n$ driven by a probability measure $\mu$ in $ \mathbb{Z}^d$. Assume that the $\mu$ has no drift, that is, the expected value of a $\mu$-distributed random variable is zero.

Let $C_n$ denote the convex hull of $X^1_n, \dots, X^m_n$ in $ \mathbb{R}^d$. When $m > d$, it is fairly easy to see that almost surely $C_n$ will contain the origin for an infinite number of values of $n$.

Question: Let $m=d$ and $B$ denote the ball of radius $1$ in $ \mathbb{R}^d$ centred at the origin. Is it the case that almost surely $C_n$ will intersect $B$ infinitely often?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I can see the case $m > d$ is pretty easy (given e.g. [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/33132/47484)), but the case $m=d$ seems more difficult to me. Could you give some hints as to why your statement is true for $m=d$?

Comment: Sorry, I meant $m=d+1$. I fixed the statement of the question accordingly. Thanks, also, for the link to the proof of the case $m=d+1$.